# References for mathematical notation for foreign students in the U.S

Tags: notation

I teach quite a few foreign students at a U.S. university.   Frequently students are placed in our most remedial math class due to not having placement scores and failing to test out of the course.
I am trying to put together a list of resources for how our terminology compares to what they are used to.  For example,  I know many parts of the world use a comma as a decimal separator where the U.S. uses a decimal point.  Other languages don't group things into groups of 1s, 10s, 100's of various units then such as [5 things](https://blog.teacherspayteachers.com/5-ways-countries-math-differently-us-important-know/)  and [Latin America to U.S.](https://www.csus.edu/indiv/o/oreyd/acp.htm_files/todos.operation.description.pdf)

Does anyone know of any such resources already made? If not,  other suggestions for how other countries do and represent things differently in primary/secondary mathematics would be helpful for me to put together my own tutorial for incoming students.

Comment: I suggest that this may not be as helpful as you think it is. You'll have students from 100 different cultures; so any particular translation tip will only be helpful for 1% of them. E.g., Last week for the first time I discovered I had a student who couldn't read Arabic digits b/c they'd been brought up with [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) instead (!). But laying that all out in a document would just confuse other students. It's better to spot-check trouble areas and help them on an as-needed basis.

Comment: And then there are different ways for notating long division, for example.